# Missing documentation on generated HTML5 of jasperreports-highcharts

Tags: jasper-reports, highcharts

we have "jasperreports-pro-5.0" and "jasperreports-highcharts-5.0" embedded in our application. When we generate Highchart Report as HTML5, using JR API, the browser fail to show the report.

Quick investigation discovered that the HTML5 is missing the references to the dependent javascripts.

We generated the report using iReport and that HTML5 included 3 javascript sources: jquery-ui, default.service, highcharts.

Did anyone encounter similar issue - the highchart html is missing javascript references? Are we missing setup of the JR?

So my question now is where is this documented? Did anyone see a description of which properties to set in order to use Highcharts?

[EDIT]

I am changing the question since I found a solution to the above.
The solution is given below.

Comment: Thanks bro the solution helped me in removing 0 from the columns.
BIG THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add relevant JasperReport properties with "$url" suffix, for example:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.jquery.ui.js$url=/script/highcharts/jquery-ui.custom.min.js
com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.highcharts.js$url=/script/highcharts/highcharts.original.src.js
```

I found this by decompiling and debugging highcharts' PropertiesResourceLocationResolver.